# Can't install the Google Assistant library on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B

Tags: python, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

I have been trying to install the Google Assistant library on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B running Raspbian Stretch with Desktop September 2017 by following the guide, [Download the Library and Run the Sample](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/develop/python/run-sample).

I created a Python virtual environment successfully. However, I couldn't install the library. A log is as follows:

```
$ python -m pip install --upgrade google-assistant-library
Collecting google-assistant-library
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/env/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 350, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/pi/env/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 837, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/pi/env/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connection.py", line 323, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/home/pi/env/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 324, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 385, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 760, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 996, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 641, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
socket.timeout: _ssl.c:704: The handshake operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/env/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/pi/env/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 353, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=conn.timeout)
  File "/home/pi/env/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 313, in _raise_timeout
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self, url, "Read timed out. (read timeout=%s)" % timeout_value)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.piwheels.hostedpi.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/home/pi/env/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 501, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/env/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/env/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/env/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/home/pi/env/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/pi/env/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 643, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/pi/env/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 315, in increment
    total -= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'
```

I tried it in a few different network environments, but the results did not change. If you have any advice on this subject, please let me know.

Comment: I'm sorry to post a question outside the scope of this service.

After about 1 hour elapsed, I tried it again, and it was able to install without problems this time. Apparently, it seems to be a temporary problem.

In the future, I will post only questions related to direct programming. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @chade_ - This was a question about errors while downloading a software library, directly involving tools used primarily for programming. The referenced documentation was from a developers site. How is this off topic?